# How to disable hyphens in Lyx BibTex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx, hyphenation

Can you prevent *all* divided-word hyphens *only* in a Lyx document's bibliography?

[image]

(*example divided-word: "Microwave" becomes Mi- on one line, crowave on another*)

Comment: Can you insert the instruction `\hyphenation{micro-wave}` in the preamble?

Comment: that would *permit*, but I am trying to *prevent* that kind of hyphenation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic method to stop hypheantion, entirely (after the macro) is to:

```
\hyphenpenalty=10000
```

Which basically tells the TeX engine that hyphenation would be really bad, worse than a more ragged line, or stretching words etc.

There are others, see https://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyphoff

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your wish to avoid seeing the word "microwave" hyphenated as "mi-crowave" *anywhere* in the document, not just in the bibliography section.

- If you want to suppress hyphenation of this word globally, just add the instruction

  ```
  \hyphenation{microwave}
  ```

  in the preamble. (If you load the `babel` package as well, be sure to insert the instruction above *after* loading `babel`.)
- If you want to permit hyphenation between "micro" and "wave", insert the instuction

  ```
  \hyphenation{micro-wave}
  ```

  in the preamble.

Comment: I think the Asker, wanted to prevent all hyphenation in the bibliography. 
Rather that just this one particular word
(Which should be possibly via setting the hyphenation penalty to huge?)

Comment: @Oxinabox - You may be right. (However, if hyphenation suppression of *all words* in the bibliography were the objective, why take the trouble to point out one specific word?) Let's hope the OP weights in and clarifies his/her objective.

Comment: @Oxinabox you are correct, setting  `\hyphenpenalty=10000` in Tex Code just before my Bibtext Generated Bibliography worked. Feel free to submit it as an answer and I'll promptly accept.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your objective. (I guess I was thrown off initially by your pointing out a specific word that shouldn't be hyphenated.) Have you checked out the posting [Stopping all hyphenation](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=hyphoff) on [The UK TeX Archive](http://www.tex.ac.uk/)?

Answer (score 1):

Won't inserting  `\raggedright`just before `\printbibliography`do the job?

Comment: I don't think there's any indication that the OP is using biblatex; hence, he/she is probably not using `\printbibliography`.